# Right pattern for downloading 100s of Images from URLs at once?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I've a situation where React web-app would download user's 100s (ex: 100-200) of images (which are less than 20MB, avg ~8MB) and goal is to show the image content on web-app's screen as soon as possible. We use JS' `<img src="URL">` for this which seems very crude way for image downloads. The images could be of type .jpg, .png and .gif.

The current experience is very bad, and we hit several network errors while JS attempting 100s of image downloads simultaneously. There are many errors ex: `failed to load resource: net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR'.

I think parallel requests using service workers can be one option. Want to understand if there are any industry standard to solve this problem.

Comment: I'm not sure about this but it seems like this has a lot of variables, such as how many hundreds, what is the size and type of the images, and what might be the limits of your own architecture.  This question is a bit too open ended as it stands, you might be better received if you can include more meaningful details.

Comment: What do I have to do to reproduce your problem?

Comment: I imagine the problem lives not in JS/React but in your backend architecture.  There are services specifically for serving images rapidly and in parallel, if your own architecture can't support it.

Comment: If they're all downloading from your own server, you may want to bundle their requests into one large download (a .zip or similar) rather than kicking off many simultaneous requests.  I'm not sure that service workers would help you at all here;  the user's bandwidth is still a limiting factor.

Comment: The issue is appearing when image size averages ~8MB or more. And, these are 100 to 200 images .jpg, .png or .gif images.

Comment: @DanielBeck we can send one batch request but downloading them in sequence and then referencing through img tag could be issue. Can't service worker help to relieve main thread and achieve more parallelization?

Comment: @unknown_boundaries - Stalinko makes an excellent point-- it seems like you are imposing much more load on your servers than is necessary.  If you are only showing a subset of the total images on the screen at one time then you should consider leveraging a [lazy loading](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Performance/Lazy_loading) approach, and if you are showing all the images on the screen at one time then you _certainly_ don't need them to be 8MB each-- you could use thumbnails.  Honestly, even if you are showing a _single_ image on screen 8MB is quite large...

Comment: "Can't service worker help to relieve main thread and achieve more parallelization?" Maybe, but it won't give the user enough bandwidth to actually download all that data before the requests time out.  Request parallelization isn't your bottleneck.

Answer (score 0):

Actually HTTP2 protocol was specifically designed for such situation. It must handle 100s of simultaneous images absolutely gracefully.

Make sure HTTP2 is properly configured on your server. `net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR` indicates there are some issues with your configuration, maybe something's wrong with SSL certificates.

The old approach for this case was: create multiple domains referencing at the same physical server to help browser fire more simultaneous requests. But with HTTP2 now it doesn't make much sense.

Comment: All the images are ~8MB and it takes time for each image to be downloaded. 100 * 8MB. The problem is not appearing when images are in few KBs.

Comment: @unknown_boundaries what's the point to load so large images all at once and keep in browser memory? It might require several GBs of RAM just for the images. Perhaps you should optimize it, load only thumbnails and get the original copies on demand.